# How to mock calls to an interface inherited from a protected resource

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, powermock

I have below code structure

```
pkg a
public class TypeA {

@Resource
protected Resource resource

//other members and methods


}

pkg a
public class TypeB extends TypeA {

public void doSomething() {
  resource.methodCall();
 }

}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for Class TypeB using powermockito, mockito for method doSomething(). I need to mock the call to resource.methodCall(), but not sure how to do it.
Changing code for TypeA or TypeB is not an option at present

Comment: to add to the question: my test case is in a different package

Comment: This can be easily tested with Mockito alone (no need for PowerMock here). You should show what you've tried so far in your test. Or, if you have no idea, I suggest taking a look at Mockito's documentation.

Comment: I appreciate the accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options here:

- naturally you look for some way to **inject** a mocked ressource object (Mockito for example has a @InjectMocks annotation that uses reflection to fill fields with mock objects). Or you create a helper constructor to get that mock to its place
- you can look into the Mockito spy concept which allows for partial mocking
- you rework your design to make it easier to test (for example by exchanging inheritance with the for good reasons favored composition)

Comment: Hello, I did try using reflection. The problem is that the resource file is protected and ReflectionUtils.findField(mock.getClass(), "resource") gives me null so I cannot mock it using reflection

Comment: Just for the heck of it I also tried to extend class TypeB created a resource member there and mocked it. In this case reflection works since it uses the "resource" on my new class, but the problem is that Java does not support member polymorphism, that's why it gives me a null pointer when the test case actually runs.

Comment: Well. You want to read [mcve] and enhance your question. When you have test code that does not do what you want - then add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have different packages I would recommend to have `getResource()` method which will be overridden in a tests:

```
pkg a
public class TypeA {
    @Resource
    protected Resource resource

    // for unit tests only
    public Resource getResource() {
        return resource;
    }
}

pkg a
public class TypeB extends TypeA {
    public void doSomething() {
      getResource().methodCall();
    }
}
```

---

In you test you override `getResource()` method to return a mocked instance:

```
@Test
public void testDoSomething() {
    Resource mockedResource = Mockito.mock(Resource.class);

    TypeB typeB = new TypeB() {
        @Override
        Resource getResource() {
            return mockedResource;
        }
    }

    typeB.doSomething();

    // verify what you need
}
```